# React native react-native-date-picker date not working?

Tags: reactjs, date, native, picker

I am picking a date with the react native date picker, date sims to update but not showing on the
date picker it self...

TNX in advanced
Harel

```
const [selectedStartDate, setSelectedStartDate] = useState(null);
const [selectedEndDate, setSelectedEndDate] = useState(null);

const onDateChange = (date, type) => {
  //function to handle the date change
  if (type === 'END_DATE') {
    setSelectedEndDate(date);
  } else {
    setSelectedEndDate(null);
    setSelectedStartDate(date);
  }
};

<ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
  <View>
    <Text style={styles.highlight}>Home screen</Text>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CalendarPicker onDateChange={onDateChange} />
      <View>
        <Text>SELECTED DATE:{startDate}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>;
```

Comment: are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-picker or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-date-picker